# Modifying Multiple Rows based on Specific Criteria

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
ID         Class      Status    Species
1          Sands        D        Carex
1          Sands        C        Eupesu
1          Sands        C        Poapra
2          Limy         D        Carcra
2          Limy         C        Eupesu
2          Limy         C        Poapra
3          Limy         D        Poapra
3          Limy         C        Eupesu
3          Limy         C        Poapra
```

When `Status` is `D` and `Species` is Carex or Carcra I want to change `Class` to `Wet` for all values within a specific ID.  My desired output is:

```
ID         Class     Status    Species
1          Wet         D        Carex
1          Wet         C        Eupesu
1          Wet         C        Poapra
2          Wet         D        Carcra
2          Wet         C        Eupesu
2          Wet         C        Poapra
3          Limy        D        Poapra
3          Limy        C        Eupesu
3          Limy        C        Poapra
```

Comment: I am simplifying the csv here, they all need to change because I am going to be summing based on `ID` eventually, and if only the `D` changes the value from `C` would be left in the old class.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: Please make your desired output consistent with the criteria as you stated it in the question.

Comment: Yes, I realized after that it could affect things, I'm sorry.  Still wrapping my head around all this stuff.

Comment: just a bad edit by me, i changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
mask = ((df['Status'] == 'D') 
        & df['Species'].isin(['Carex','Carcra']))
mask = mask.groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')
df.loc[mask, 'Class'] = 'Wet'
print(df)
```

yields

```
   ID Class Status Species
0   1   Wet      D   Carex
1   1   Wet      C  Eupesu
2   1   Wet      C  Poapra
3   2   Wet      D  Carcra
4   2   Wet      C  Eupesu
5   2   Wet      C  Poapra
6   3  Limy      D  Poapra
7   3  Limy      C  Eupesu
8   3  Limy      C  Poapra
```

---

The assignment

```
df['mask'] = ((df['Status'] == 'D') 
        & df['Species'].isin(['Carex','Carcra']))
```

makes `df` look like this:

```
In [166]: df
Out[166]: 
   ID  Class Status Species   mask
0   1  Sands      D   Carex   True
1   1  Sands      C  Eupesu  False
2   1  Sands      C  Poapra  False
3   2   Limy      D  Carcra   True
4   2   Limy      C  Eupesu  False
5   2   Limy      C  Poapra  False
6   3   Limy      D  Poapra  False
7   3   Limy      C  Eupesu  False
8   3   Limy      C  Poapra  False
```

Now, (thanks to DSM):

```
mask = ((df['Status'] == 'D') 
        & df['Species'].isin(['Carex','Carcra']))
mask = mask.groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')
```

groups `mask` by `df['ID']`, and assigns `True` to all the rows of that group if *any* value in the original `mask` is True, and `False` otherwise.

```
In [168]: mask
Out[168]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool
```

`df.loc` can be used to select rows and columns from `df`.
`df.loc[mask]` selects the rows where `mask` is True:

```
In [169]: df.loc[mask]
Out[169]: 
   ID  Class Status Species   mask
0   1  Sands      D   Carex   True
1   1  Sands      C  Eupesu  False
2   1  Sands      C  Poapra  False
3   2   Limy      D  Carcra   True
4   2   Limy      C  Eupesu  False
5   2   Limy      C  Poapra  False
```

`df.loc[mask, 'Class']` further selects the column `Class`:

```
In [170]: df.loc[mask, 'Class']
Out[170]: 
0    Sands
1    Sands
2    Sands
3     Limy
4     Limy
5     Limy
Name: Class, dtype: object
```

`df.loc[mask]['Class'] = value` may fail to modify `df` since `df.loc[mask]` returns a copy. (The same holds true of `df[mask]['Class'] = value`). Using `[...]` twice is called "chained indexing" and the problem can be avoided if we avoid chained indexing.

So instead of using `[...]` twice, use, `df.loc[mask, 'Class'] = 'Wet'`:

```
In [172]: df
Out[172]: 
   ID Class Status Species
0   1   Wet      D   Carex
1   1   Wet      C  Eupesu
2   1   Wet      C  Poapra
3   2   Wet      D  Carcra
4   2   Wet      C  Eupesu
5   2   Wet      C  Poapra
6   3  Limy      D  Poapra
7   3  Limy      C  Eupesu
8   3  Limy      C  Poapra
```

Comment: This returned 1 column of `FALSE`

Comment: The code above should work on the data that you posted and is consistent with your description of the criteria if not the desired output. Since we know nothing of your real csv, all we can try to do is solve the problem as it is posed in the question. I have no idea why the code above should result in a column of `FALSE` values.

Comment: I created a DataFrame identical to the one posted and it returns: True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False

Comment: Those might be values of `mask`. The line `df.loc[mask, 'Class'] = 'Wet'` will alter values in `df`. The rows are selected by the boolean mask, and the column is specified as `'Class'`.

Comment: After all the updates I think what the OP is after is a mask like `mask.groupby(df.ID).transform("any")` after you drop the ID condition from your mask = line.  (BTW, belated happy-new-name!)

Comment: I see, as you noticed I was incorrectly printing mask instead of df.  This only changes the rows associated with `D` to `Wet` though whereas I need all values within a specific `ID` to change to `Wet`

Comment: Stefano, okay, I think I understand what "values within a specific ID" means now. @DSM: thanks for the help interpreting the question -- and in fact the solution!

Comment: Yea, I couldn't figure out a good way to phrase it.  Thanks so much for bearing with the numerous edits and helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You tagged pandas so I'm assuming you can import this in as a dataframe.

If so, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
df[(df.Status=='D') & (df.Species=='CareX' | df.Species=='Carcra') & (df.ID== 1)]['Class'] = 'Wet'
```

Comment: This returned `TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]
`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this answer may be inefficient because it takes all the rows in the file to memory. In order to edit only that part of the file, well, I'll look into and edit this answer later. But for now, if you have a file that isn't more than, I don't know, 50mb?, just use this.

```
lines = []
theID = 1
for line in open("file.csv", "r"):
    row = line.split(",")
    if row[2] == "D":
        if row[3] == "Carex" or row[3] == "Carcra":
            if theID == row[0]:
                row[1] = "Wet"
    lines.append(",".join(row))

open("file.csv", "w").writelines(lines)
```

Please please please backup your actual file before running this because it could mess up the entire thing. (Untested)